# SVD: Time Series Similarity Measure

Tags: svd, time-series, pattern-recognition, singular-values, clustering

I am currently implementing a multivariate time series pattern recognition algorithm from "Pattern Recognition and Classification for Multivariate Time Series" (Spiegel et al. 2011). It starts by using SVD to divide the time series into segments (of non-equal length) at those points, where the correlation structure of the variables seems to change. So far so good, I already succeeded by coding the first part.

The second part concerns the clustering of the obtained segments and I can't manage to get the SVD similarity measure right (will be used afterwards in agglomerative hierarchical clustering). From the paper:
[Classification Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaVWU.png).
As far as I understand, the SVD similarity measure should yield a value between 0 and 1, but the values I obtain don't make much sense since they are quite large and also negative. Let's say I want to compare the two segments i and j, denoted by matrices $X_i$ & $X_j$ (variables in columns, each row is a point in time/observation):

1. I start by mean centering both segments
2. Then I calculate the SVD for each segment, using k dimensions: $U_{i,k}\Sigma_{i,k}V_{i,k}^T$ as well as $U_{j,k}\Sigma_{j,k}V_{j,k}^T$
3. According to Spiegel et. al 2011:

> Then the similarity between
> these subspaces can be defined as the sum of the squares of the cosines of the angles between each vector of matrix Wi,k and Wj,k, which are composed by multiplying the respective singular values and right-singular vectors ($W_{i,k} = \Sigma_{i,k}V_{i,k}$ and $W_{j,k} = \Sigma_{j,k}V_{j,k}$). This similarity measure is formalized by the following equation:
> $$S_{SVD} = \frac{1}{k} trace((W^T_i W_j)(W^T_j W_i))$$

First of all, I think the expression in the brackets (in text) regarding $W_{i,k}$ and $W_{j,k}$ is wrong. If we reduced the dimensionality to k dimensions for a segment $X$ that got dimensions n x m, the matrix $\Sigma$ would have dimensions k x k and $V^T$ would have dimensions k x m. Therefore, I perform $W_{i,k} = \Sigma_{i,k}V_{i,k}^T$ instead of $W_{i,k} = \Sigma_{i,k}V_{i,k}$. Otherwise I would have a dimensionality mismatch.

4. After obtaining $W$ as described before, I stick to his definition of $S_{SVD}$ and multiply the (transposed) $W$ matrices of the two segments, take the trace of the result and divide it by the number of dimensions.

Here is my Python3 code (runs in a loop and fetches segments from list of all segments at beginning):

```
        # fetch segment data that gets analyzed and mean-center it
        first_segment = segmented_signals[i]
        first_segment = first_segment - first_segment.mean(axis=0)
        second_segment = segmented_signals[j]
        second_segment = second_segment - second_segment.mean(axis=0)

        # decompose segments via SVD
        first_svd = np.linalg.svd(first_segment, full_matrices=False)
        second_svd = np.linalg.svd(second_segment, full_matrices=False)

        # extract necessary matrices of decomposition
        first_svd_sigma = np.diag(first_svd[1])[0:svd_dims, 0:svd_dims]
        first_svd_vh = first_svd[2][0:svd_dims, :]
        second_svd_sigma = np.diag(second_svd[1])[0:svd_dims, 0:svd_dims]
        second_svd_vh = second_svd[2][0:svd_dims, :]

        # scaled rsv matrices
        first_rsv_matrix = first_svd_sigma @ first_svd_vh
        second_rsv_matrix = second_svd_sigma @ second_svd_vh

        similarity = (1/svd_dims) * np.trace((first_rsv_matrix.T @ second_rsv_matrix)
                                             @ (second_rsv_matrix.T @ first_rsv_matrix))
```

As I said, I seem to obtain arbitrary numbers for the similarity measure, often very high and also negative, for example the first segment with itself results in -4.21861211e+03, while I would think it should yield 1 to be interpretable as the highest level of similarity.

I am very thankful for any help and hope the questions is understandable & provides the necessary information, if not don't hesitate to ask for more detail. Here is a link to the paper:
https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Stephan_Spiegel/publication/254003630_Pattern_recognition_and_classification_for_multivariate_time_series/links/0f31753a929a3d72ef000000.pdf

Greetings & Thanks in advance

Comment: UPDATE: I figured out that I received negative values as a consequence of a a part in my code, where I subtracted the similarity measure from 1 to obtain a distance measure. But since my values were bigger than 1, I obtained negative values in my prints. So all values are strictly positive as expected. And furthermore I just removed the multiplication with the singular values, as this step scales the right singular values so that I would have to divide the vector product by the product of their lengths to obtain the cosine value. Just using the (unit length?!) RSVs yields values between 0 & 1!

Comment: Still I don't understand why Spiegel et. al 2011 define the matrix $W$ as a product of the singular values with the RSVs

Comment: I've found that in situations like this, where you are experiencing ambiguity or uncertainty about a highly specific work e.g. a research paper (as opposed to say an exercise in a well-known textbook), it doesn't hurt to email the author. More often than not, I've found that they are prepared to make time to answer your queries, although that is a hope, rather than an expectation.